# CSS mobile image distortion issue

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm working on a website which has one panel of three images that form sort of a banner across the screen. like so, like the first image. When I view it on an iPhone or iPad, the images are vertically stretched, as shown in the second image. This doesn't appear to be a browser issue, as the problem persists both on Chrome and Safari, but it also isn't simply a matter of viewport width, since when I use the same vw on my computer, I don't get this problem. I cleared my browser cache and the problem persisted. What is interesting is that this is not true for all images on the website; most of them do not have this problem.

Desktop: https://ibb.co/TWQ4S70
Mobile: https://ibb.co/Km7k4NF

The HTML and CSS for the pictures attached is below:

HTML:

```
 <div class="panel-3">
        <img src="/img/matthew-james-dunham.jpg" title="Matthew Weathers (MM 2019), playing in masterclass for Rice University viola professor James Dunham"
        ><img src="/img/nuso-violas.jpg" title="Members of the studio play in the Northwestern University Symphony Orchestra viola section"
        ><img src="/img/sae-rheen.jpg" title="Sae Rheen Kim (BM 2020) plays in studio class">
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.panel-3 {
    display: flex;
    padding: 10px;
}

.panel-3 img {
    width: calc(100% / 3);
}
```

Any idea what could be happening here?

Comment: if an answer worked would you kindly mark as the best answer?

Answer (score 1):

Image distortion is never fun. A simple solution is to use the [object-fit](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_object-fit.asp) css attribute to define the images behavior when its container is distorted.

```
panel-3 {
    display: flex;
    padding: 10px;
}

.panel-3 img {
    width: calc(100% / 3);
    height: auto;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

Comment: This didn't exactly work - the images aren't distorted anymore, but I'm continuing to have the issue in which the image height increases dramatically on mobile instead of scaling down with the width. Any idea why that is?

Comment: If you inspect the image and container components in the browser, do they have any CSS attributes that you did not include in your example above? To me this seems like the container (panel-3) has some attributes you did not realize. try setting panel-3 height to auto or a set number and width to 100%.